# JDS6600 signal generator - broken or normal?

Tags: flyback, signal-generator

I recently treated myself to a [JDS6600-60M](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32818958756.html) signal generator. It's a (very) cheap one but that's because electronics is just a hobby and not something I make money with or anything.

The other day I noticed that at very low frequencies (1-10Hz) the pulse wave looks like this:

[image: 10Hz]

10Hz

[image: 1Hz]

1Hz

I'm not quite sure if it did this before and when I increase the frequency the pulse gets more and more 'square' as you'd expect. From about 100Hz it looks pretty ok:

[image]

Still a bit 'round' but better and from about 200-250Hz upwards it looks fine.

Now I got to thinking and suddenly I realized I had used the signal generator about a week earlier to toggle [a relay](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32704987837.html) on and off (just for test-purposes) at about 1Hz frequency. And then it dawned on me that this could've cause some pretty serious flyback which may have damaged the signal generator? I had hooked the relay coil straight up to the leads to the signal generator; no flyback diode or anything else.

So my question(s) is/are:

1. Did I break my signal generator? Or is this "normal" (for cheap signal generators)?
2. Maybe someone with a JDS6600 can confirm this?

The manual has this to say about it:

[image: Specs]

From what I gather it should be able to generate a signal from 0 to 15Mhz but I don't know if it's supposed to be guaranteed* a square signal over the entire range. Also: It let's me adjust up to 60Mhz just fine for a square wave and I can confirm this on my scope (though at the higher frequencies the square starts to look like a sine, which is pretty normal I think for a 110MHz,1GSa/s (also cheap) scope).

<sub>* As far as cheap devices make, let alone meet, these 'guarantees' ofcourse.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite possible that your oscilloscope is measuring with the coupling feature set to AC. This will block DC levels and entirely produce what you show in your pictures. This symbol might be the clue: -

[image]

Comment: I'm an idiot ‍♂️ Thank you very much. I'm looking at very nice square waves now! Even at 1Hz. I will accept this answer as soon as stackexchange will let me. In my defense: I'm all pretty new to this and usually don't have much of a clue to what I'm doing 

Comment: @RobIII we've all done it LOL

Comment: Out of interest: COULD I have damaged it this way? (If I had to answer it myself: I guess so?) Or would a signal generator have some protections against idiots like me - maybe just not the cheap ones?

Comment: If you are talking about the flyback issue, sure, damage may occur but, if it looks like it's working then it's probably OK. Flyback damage usually causes a fairly instant and obvious fault.